# When changing from 4 to 3 voices for a series of parallel 63 chords how do you go back to 4 voices?

Tags: voice-leading

[image]

I am trying to go back to 4 voices on the last beat as you can see but this seems strange. When you go back to 4 voices can you just use a 4th voice wherever you want? I chose to use the tenor in this case.

Comment: One approach is to imagine that in the previous part some pair of the voices are in unison... and then split back to four distinct voices. So the "new" fourth voice should make some sort of sense as an extension of one of the previous lines.

Comment: so like the the C# on beat 3 in the bass would split into the  B and F#?

Comment: For example. Yeah, I'd want to consider whether that "works" as voices. C# to B is obviously easy, but C# to F# is a little jump...

Comment: Ok but isnt doubling one voice keeping 4 voices? in this case I really switch to 3 voices and then back to 4 so why should the added voice pretend to come from the doubled C#?

Comment: Well, maybe there _are_ no "rules" about re-entry of a voice that had gone quiet for a while, if you're really not thinking of it as being doubled for a little bit. But, yes, then, how to make its re-entrance sound good...? Dunno.